# Ktor client - Basic Auth does not work from install(), must be added to each request?

Tags: kotlin, authentication, client, basic-authentication, ktor

I have a Ktor client requesting from a server with Basic Auth.

When I `install()` the Basic Auth as per the docs, it does not work - I get back HTTP 401.

```kotlin
val response1 =
    HttpClient(Java.create()) {
        install(Auth) {
            basic {
                credentials {
                    BasicAuthCredentials("foo@example.com", pass)
                }
            }
        }
    }
   .use { it.get("https://mycompany.something.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request") }
```

I need to add the Auth to the request to make it work:

```
      .use { 
          it.get("https://mycompany.something.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request") {
              basicAuth("foo@example.com", pass)
          }
      }
```

Why is not the auth set up in the client enough? Am I doing something wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting, I found out that it is de facto a duplicate of [Ktor client Auth feature does not sending Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362485/ktor-client-auth-feature-does-not-sending-authorization-header)

So, in short: For some reason, by default, Ktor opts not to send the `Authorization` header until it fails authorization. Which is not too fortunate decision IMHO.

This can be changed by `sendWithoutRequest { true }`:

```
    install(Auth) {
        basic {
            sendWithoutRequest { true }
            credentials { BasicAuthCredentials(user, pass) }
        }
    }
```